# AngularStrap - Load only the necessary modules

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

AngularStrap's documentation states something like this.

```
Plugin dependency
Datepickers require the tooltip module and dateParser helper module to be loaded.

These docs currently use bootstrap-additions for styling purposes.
```

Im using angular material as of now and I want to use angularstrap's datepicker but I dont want to load the whole angularstrap. Is it possible to just load the datepicker module(and also scrollspy module)? And if possible, how to?

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer is also in their documentation [here](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/getting-started) under "Getting Started" then "Custom Builds"